# Port 6379 is occupied by a process with PID '-' in wsl2

Tags: ubuntu, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kill, netstat

I want to initiate redis-server on port 6379 but i got this:
Could not create server TCP listening socket *:6379: bind: Address already in use
And here is the output of netstat -tunlp :
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
How to kill this process ...?

Comment: Try to run `sudo netstat ...`, then you can see PID.

Comment: the pid i get is '-'..even with sudo

Answer (score 2):

Try to restart WSL by using `wsl --shutdown` and then try again.

Or maybe some windows app on your computer is using this port and is preventing Linux from getting information about this process.